# How to fix "Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response with MIME type application/json." issue?

Tags: vue.js, axios, laravel-5.6

I'm currently developing the frontend (VueJS) for a project and to test my login and register logics I'm using laravel as backend, though we'll be actually working with springboot for backend. I was coding in a desktop and everything was normal. So I just started to work with my laptop. I got the same project, everything is equal. When I use postman to make the requests, it works normally, but when I try to make them with the form from my website, I get that error.

I've looked everywhere but couldn't fix it. Nothing I tryed did work. And It seems that no one else had a similar problem.

Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54705229/why-did-not-working-laravel-middleware-cors-with-vue-js/54705381#54705381

Comment: Thanks, it worked!!

Comment: I used the command "google-chrome --disable-web-security" on terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add proxy configuration in `vue.config.js` file

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: 'http://localhost:4000'
  }
}
```

This will tell the dev server to proxy any unknown requests (requests that did not match a static file) to http://localhost:4000.

here is a [link](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver) to the doc for more detail