# Why did Not working Laravel middleware CORS with Vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, cors

working with Laravel 5.7 as backend and Vue.js as frontend. so, I need send http request fron Vue to Laravel backend. so, I used Laravel CORS package to using github link as following https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors  but it is not sucess and (not pass data to table fron vue). and my console error is `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8000/api/addItem. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

how can fix this error?`

Answer (score 3):

It is only for localhost & in production if you use `https` then this issue will not raise any more. However for local test you can open chrome browser in disabled security mode. Details about how to do

[Access-Control-Allow-Origin (Laravel & Vue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54545554/access-control-allow-origin-laravel-vue/54545748#54545748)

Comment: how can I do this for firefox?

Comment: There are some articles available online to disable web security in firefox but these not worked. You can check in IE11 there should be no issue as web security not implemented like chrome there