# Spotify Token request fails in Chrome

Tags: angular, google-chrome, spotify

Requesting a token with Spotify Web API in "client_credentials" mode, I receive a 200 response with null content when working with Chrome. The same code works fine with Firefox and Opera.

I'm making an App in Angular7 for getting music information from Spotify  and linking it with the actual lyrics. The Chrome behaviour is different as expected when I try to get a token to query Spotify with. Apparently the headers of the request and the response are well, but the answer where the token object should be is empty. The behaviour with Opera and Firefox, as said above is fine.

The method to get the token is included in the constructor of the Spotify service in an Angular 7 App:

```
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    const authString: string = btoa(SpotifyService.CLIENT_ID+':'+ SpotifyService.CLIENT_SECRET);
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + authString
    });

    const params = new HttpParams()
      .set('grant_type', 'client_credentials')
      .append('json', 'true');
    this.http.post(SpotifyService.URL_TOKEN, params, {headers})
      .subscribe((res: token) => {
        console.log('token: ', res.access_token);
        console.log('expires in (s):', res.expires_in);
        console.log('Object: ', res);
        this.token = res.access_token;
        this.expiration = new Date().getTime() / 1000 + res.expires_in;
        console.log('now: ', new Date().getTime() / 1000);
        console.log('expiration: ', this.expiration);
      });


  }
```

The response to the query in Chrome has a 200 OK Status Code but it is empty. Also, I have a warning with the following message:
"Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token with MIME type application/json"
I don't know if the warning is related to the problem or because the response is empty.

As said before, the response in Opera and Firefox is well formed with the object containing the actual token, as expected:

```
{"access_token":"BQClMOsKt1LF0--kly0XWdfxkiWhI4nNqluiiZxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx4EZDT_mRxDSb625E-z2j4yf4","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600,"scope":""}
```

Thanks!

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54705229/why-did-not-working-laravel-middleware-cors-with-vue-js/54705381#54705381

Comment: Also, try passing "User-Agent" in header of the request with value `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36 OPR/38.0.2220.41`

Comment: Try adding: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Comment: I recommend using an interceptor to add the token and add the header

Comment: @Paul, the Access-Control--Allow-Origin doesn't make any change. Could you explain a little deeper your interceptor idea? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I meant @Pari.

Comment: Well if the error from google is a cors error then it means you haven’t configured your site to accept external responses. I’m some cases wildcard access control is not accepted (if you are passing with data) so check the error in the console and it will tell you.

Comment: @kushal.8, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54705229/why-did-not-working-laravel-middleware-cors-with-vue-js/54705381#54705381 worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: @HarryAngstrom Kudos!!